# Get notified when widget become visible

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget that need to be updated once it becomes visible, for example when user unlock the screen, or when home screen become visible after closing the current running app. How can I get a notification when this happen?

I tried using broadcast receiver that listen for ACTION_USER_PRESENT (android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT), but it doesn't seem to be working for android 8+.

Comment: There is no broadcast for that event, sorry. People have been asking for that for years and years.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. Any hacks around it?

Comment: None that I am aware of. The idea is that you update the app widget when the data changes, on a periodic basis, or when the user interacts with the app widget (e.g., clicks a button that triggers your `PendingIntent`).

Answer (score -1):

You can have a try with the following tow ways:

1.register an `View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` to your view.That's the official link:[register lister](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility#java)

2.when someing changed,get the visibility of the view.For example:
`activity.onResume..`,`view.onAttachedToWindow`.